# Example of unbounded linear operator on space of sequences $C_{00}$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, solution-verification

If $c_{00}$ be the space of sequences with a finite number of non-zero elements with $\|.\|_\infty$ norm and  $\Gamma : c_{00} \to c_{00}$ a linear operator. Is there any example of unbounded linear operator?

I was thinking to give the following if $x = (x_1,x_2,...)$, then $\Gamma x_i = a_i x_i$, where $\{a_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be I be an unbounded sequence of real numbers.

But then such a transformation is not $c_{00} \to c_{00}$, right? Since $\Gamma x \notin c_{00}$.

---

Also , I have a confusion in general. We have that the operator is a self map $\Gamma : c_{00} \to c_{00}$ , it means that $\Gamma x \in c_{00}$ , since $c_{00} \subset l^\infty \implies \sup\{\Gamma x_i, \forall i\}<\infty$. Then how could the operator to be unbounded?

Comment: What about something like this: Let $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ be such that $x_1=(1,\frac{1}{2},0,...)$, $x_2=(1,\frac{1}{3},0,...)$, $x_3=(1,\frac{1}{4},0,...)$ so that $\forall n, ||x_n||_{\infty}=1$. Define $T:c_{00} \rightarrow c_{00}$ as $T(x)=(min_{k \in \mathbb{N}}x_k,0,0,...)$. Then it is well defined, continuous and since $T(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ then its inverse can not be bounded.

Comment: but I want that the linear map $T(x_n)$ to be unbounded, not the inverse.

Comment: But your answer would be the inverse map of $T$!

Comment: you're right. But I guess I also have not understood your mapping ? This means 

$\\ T(x_1) = (x_1 , 0, ....) \\ $ , $T(x_2) = (x_1 ,\min\{x_1,x_2\},0,0...)=(x_1,x_2,0,0...)\\$ , $T(x_3) = (x_1 ,\min\{x_1,x_2,x_3\},0,0...)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,0,0...), \dots \\$ $T(x_n) = (x_1 ,x_2,\dots , \dots,\min\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}, 0,0,0,0 ) = (x_1 , x_2 , x_3, \dots, x_k , 0,0,0,)$ ?

Comment: No. It only takes to the first coordinate the minimum value in the coordinates of all of $x$'s so in the fashion of how $\{ x_n \}$ is defined, $T$ can well be defined as $T(x)=(x_2,0,0,....)$. You might have to make some minor corrections in order to get $t^{-1}$ right but I think with this idea in mind it will not be hard to find what you look for. Regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $T:C_{00}\rightarrow C_{00}$ by $(Tx)(n)=nx_{n}$. Clearly
$T$ is a well-defined map, and is linear. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
let $\delta^{(n)}\in C_{00}$ be defined as $\delta_{k}^{(n)}=\begin{cases}
1, & \mbox{if }k=n\\
0, & \mbox{if }k\neq n
\end{cases}.$ Note that $||\delta^{(n)}||=1$ but $||T\delta^{(n)}||=n$. Hence,
$T$ is unbounded.

Comment: This is an exercise in "Lecture Notes on Functional Analysis". The question also asks to show in the example that the linear map is not continuous. (In fact, I think aims to not using the equivalence of boundedness and continuity.)

Is the following correct way of showing this? 
let $x,y \in C_{00}$ , s.t. $\|x_n-y_n\|_\infty \le \eta$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for some $\eta >0$. Then;

$$\|Tx_n-Ty_n\|_\infty = \|T(x_n-y_n)\|_\infty =n \to \infty$$, so it is not continuous.

Comment: Boundedness and continuity are equivalent for linear operators. In fact this both are also equivalent to uniform continuity and continuity at zero, so proving any one of them yields the other three.